# There is no action mapped etc.. In Struts 2

Tags: struts2, web.xml, action-mapping

Yet another question on this I know, but let me just say I looked everything else or about. So, I'm currently building the structure of my Struts 2 Project. I use Struts 2.3.4, JBoss 7.1 and Eclipse Indigo. I also included all the necessary jar into my project. The problem is when I run my application (Add project to Jboss, Run On Server) and go "http://localhost:8080/booxstore/" I get this:

```
Etat HTTP 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [] associated with context path [/booxstore]
```

[image: Project]

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Booxstore</display-name> 

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

My struts.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
 "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

 <struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <package name="pages" namespace="/pages" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="afficher" class="com.booxstore.controller.DisplayAction" >
            <result name="SUCCESS">/center.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
 </struts>
```

My action :

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.booxstore.controller;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class DisplayAction extends ActionSupport {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8199854978749642334L;

    public String execute() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("IN");
        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

My JSP just have plain text and have imported struts 2 tags. Basically no matter what I do I can't get a resource. If I go to "http://localhost:8080/booxstore/" or "http://localhost:8080/booxstore/DisplayAction" I get "There is no action mapped" and if I tried to access directly the jsp I get a 404. Please note my war is deployed and enabled on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `index.jsp` under `WebContent` folder, move `pages` folder to `WEB-INF` and then change the struts.xml with:

```
<struts>
 <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
 <package name="pages" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="afficher" class="com.booxstore.controller.DisplayAction" >
        <result name="SUCCESS">/WEB-INF/pages/center.jsp</result>
    </action>
 </package>
</struts>
```

I think that the problem is that the application is not finding the jsps that you are putting in the configuration files. And `META-INF` folder is not the place for putting your jsps pages if you don't want to make them public, `WEB-INF` is better for that purpose.

Comment: Prove this now, without `namespace="/pages"`

Comment: Index is ok and now the action result is "undefined" but successful. Wrong path ?

Comment: You have to access to the action as: `http://localhost:8080/afficher.action`, because that's the action's name.

Comment: afficher or afficher.action give me the same answer

Comment: If you move `center.jsp` to `WebContent` and you replace the actual result with `center.jsp` (instead of `/WEB-INF...`), are you having the same problem?

Comment: Yes I do have the same problem, which is weird.

Comment: Ok I found out why... The SUCCESS written in the result tag should be lower case because the enum is indeed lower case. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent misunderstandings about mappings, add the config browser plugin jar to your application. It will allow you to browse all pages. Caution! Only deploy the dependency in dev or testing, never ond production. Use maven profiles for this restrictions.

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/config-browser-plugin.html